# Should I add a disclaimer to my answers?

Tags: discussion

On some questions related to hacking, I'm not 100% sure whether the person has permission to do it or not.

In those cases, does it make sense to add a disclaimer to my answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not our policy to not answer if we do not know if there is permission or not, so the disclaimer is unnecessary.